# Unable to slice data frame correctly

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, tkinter

I dont know why I kee getting error here :

```
col_list = []
for k in self.vars.keys():
        if self.vars[k].get() == 1:
              col_list.append(k)
self.df = self.df.loc[:, col_list]
```

KeyError: "None of [['Occupancy Scene']] are in the [columns]"

Comment: What does `self.df.columns` show as columns?

Comment: They are different columns than one I am filtering.  It was not showing till I restarted jupyter notebook. Thanks

Comment: @NehaBhushan can you post in the full code?

Comment: I was able to fix the error... Thanks. In case you still want the code, I will send you